# CNN: Difficulties understanding backward pass derivatives

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, backpropagation

I have really quite hard difficulties to understand what is actually going on in the backward pass of a CNN.

I am currently focusing on these references:

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/forward-and-backward-propagations-for-2d-convolutional-layers-ed970f8bf602
2. https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbook.io/artificial-inteligence/machine_learning/deep_learning/convolution_layer

At the moment, **I only want to compute the gradient which is then passed to the next lower layer.**

I tried to implement the last equation on this image (from [1]):

https://miro.medium.com/max/2400/1*K2K0tfxmAlyRlqqbj4z0Rg@2x.png

For me, this formula looks like 6 nested for-loops.

The first for the channel `c`, the second for the output height `i`, the third for the output height `j`, the fourth for the number of kernels `f`, the fith for the kernel height `m` and the sixth for the kernel width `n`.

Am I wrong? I tried to implement this but I always get an out of bounds error.

Someone here who doesn't mind going a bit more into detail?

Any tips are greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello. This post seems to be either off-topic (because it may be a programming issue) or too broad. I recommend that you take a look at our [on-topic page](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).